# script only working in Studio

Tags: lua, roblox

//EDIT: yes i added the 2nd parameter GPE and if not gpe then return end in case someone nitpicks unnecessary details

Another problem is that it is quite long but if you read it and see something wrong then let me know. Also I have put this as a LocalScript in Startpack.

```
local uis = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local torso = script.Parent.Parent.Character.Torso or script.Parent.Parent.Character.UpperTorso
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local db = true

function move(x)
local velocity = Instance.new("BodyVelocity")
velocity.Velocity = torso.CFrame.lookVector*50
velocity.MaxForce = Vector3.new(math.huge, math.huge, math.huge)
velocity.Parent = x
end

uis.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.R and db then
db = false

local part = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").Union:Clone()
part.CFrame = torso.CFrame + torso.CFrame.lookVector*10
part.Parent = game.Workspace

local effect = game.ReplicatedStorage.Waterfall:Clone()
effect.CFrame = part.CFrame

local light = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").PointLight:Clone()
light.Parent = part

local weld = Instance.new("ManualWeld")
weld.Part0 = part
weld.Part1 = effect
weld.Parent = part
effect.Parent = part

local goal3 = {}
goal3.Size = Vector3.new(120,70,70)

local goal4 = {}
goal4.Size = goal3.Size

local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(2)

local tween3 = TweenService:Create(part, tweenInfo, goal3)
local tween4 = TweenService:Create(effect,tweenInfo, goal4)

tween3:Play(); tween4:Play()

game.Lighting.Blur.Enabled = true; game.Lighting.ColorCorrection.Enabled = true

move(part)
part.Anchored = false
effect.Anchored = false
move(effect)

local goal = {}
goal.Size = Vector3.new(30,7,7)
goal.Transparency = 0.4

local goal2 = {}
goal2.Size = goal.Size

local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(3)

local tween = TweenService:Create(part, tweenInfo, goal)
local tween2 = TweenService:Create(effect,tweenInfo, goal2)

tween:Play(); tween2:Play()

game:GetService("Debris"):AddItem(part,2)
game:GetService("Debris"):AddItem(effect,2)
wait(.5)
game.Lighting.Blur.Enabled = false; game.Lighting.ColorCorrection.Enabled = false
db = true

end
end)
```

**The thing is pretty straightforward, It doesn't work when I publish the game and play it, but it only works in Roblox Studio.
It is not Filtering Enabled yet, and still doesn't work. I don't know exactly.**

Comment: btw i know i should have put the tweens in a function but ill do it later

Comment: https://snag.gy/tyTAxO.jpg

Comment: thats how it looks like while im in studio test mode

Comment: https://www.roblox.com/games/861660317/test

Comment: that's the link to my place and u can see nothing happens when you press R

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it lol i just moved the localscript from starterpack to startercharacter :D

Comment: obviously changed the torso variable